# Question about soft cures and curing salts

Tags: salt, curing

I was advised that your curing salts should be added 0.2% of the salt by weight, so if you have 125kg worth of koshering salt, that is 250grams of curing salt. Can the same be done when you have 100kg kosher salts and 25kg brown sugar, how does the softness of the cure affect the amount of curing salts that you should add?

Comment: When referring to pink salt, please clarify what salt you are referring to.  Himalayan Pink salt is a a table salt, not a curing salt and its current popularity adds to the confusion.  Prague #1, often dyed pink and referred to as pink salt is 6.25% sodium nitrite,93.75% sodium chloride, no nitrate. Prague #2 also has sodium nitrate in it, is sometimes also dyed pink, sometimes yellow, Some formulas put 1% nitrate into cure 2, others 4%.  To have a chance of answering any ratio questions you must first know which you have.

Comment: Ok I have made an edit.